# Are elements on the same level as head and body allowed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a browser extension and want to inject a CSS file directly when the page loads. However, I want to do this with Javascript and not via the manifest with

```
"css": ["styles.css"],
```

because I want to check the user's settings beforehand.
The problem is that when the CSS file is injected, there is often no head or body yet.
That is why I have so far chosen the solution of appending the CSS directly to the root element:

```js
let stylesheet = document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.rel = "stylesheet";
stylesheet.id = "link";
stylesheet.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("styles.css");
document.querySelector("html").appendChild(stylesheet);
```

This works, but feels a bit hacky. Is it allowed in HTML to have a stylesheet or other elements on the same level as head and body?

Thanks

Comment: No, the only allowed children of `html` are `head` and `body`. Have you tried `document.head`?

Comment: The problem is that the head does not yet exist when I want to add the stylesheet. Of course I can wait until the head exists, but the problem with this is that the style changes from white mode to dark mode and therefore always causes the white page to flash very briefly before the CSS is injected.

Comment: What do you mean? `head` will exist when the javascript runs, since it has to for the script tag to exist.

Comment: @evolutionxbox If I run the following script at "document_start":
console.log(document.querySelector("head"));
Then _null_ is output. The head does not exist immediately.

Comment: @grottenolm what about `document.head`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Using `console.log(document.head);` also results in _null_

Comment: Will your extension still work if you run at `document_end` instead?

Comment: I just read your comment on the first answer. If you want to check whether the user has dark mode enabled, this is possible with CSS. See if it works to inject your CSS from the manifest and add `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { html, body { background: #222; } }`.

Comment: @agrm Thank you, that is helpful. But in my specific case, unfortunately I want to check settings from the popup and not just the OS default theme settings.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that.
Directly create a listener to exec when de DOM load:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  const head = document.querySelector('head')
  ...
});
```

Comment: Of course I can wait until the `head` exists, but the problem with this is that the style changes from white mode to dark mode and therefore always causes the white page to flash very briefly before the CSS is injected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).